# Video does not appear on top of leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I try to insert a video element with html with the following code:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg">
                Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

The above works when I run it standalone but when I try to insert it on top of my leaflet map, this is how it appears.

[image]

What might be causing the transparent display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in your code is wrong as you see the example below works fine. I added the same video as you.

```js
/**
 * Simple map
 */

// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZomm: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.2297700;
const lon = 21.0117800;

// calling map
const map = L.map('map', config).setView([lat, lon], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body,
html,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg">
      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
    </video>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Code works fine when I run it here, but the video appears black if I try to run it on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mxqdkft3/

Also I tried to run it on my IDE (webstorm) and the map does not appear in the background, only the video in top left corner.
Obviously I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I wouldn't care about https://jsfiddle.net/, it's just a website that doesn't always work well. It is important that it works well in your environment. The problem also occurs on codepen.io there console.log shows `https://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` something wrong with this file and redirects.
But locally this example works fine for me.

Comment: It seems like the problem is that the video window appears behind the map. Here's a snip: https://ibb.co/v4nmRY2 . Now the question is how do I bring the video element to the front?

Comment: Add your code on https://codepen.io/ or on github and link here. Unfortunately, without the code, there is little chance for help.
I prepared a working example just with a different file [example](https://codepen.io/Tomik23/pen/ZEQqJYG)

Comment: Here's it is https://codepen.io/Chris232397/pen/xxZyLVq

Comment: Add these styles to the codes and you will have the video above the map `video {position: absolute; z-index: 9999; } `

Comment: Yes just figured it out too. Thank you!